# Conditional expectation for weights

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

What is the advantage of having the conditional expectation from von Neumann algebra to its subalgebra?? One thing I know the existence of conditional expectation gives characterization $\sigma$- finite von Neumann algebra. Does conditional expectation depend on Hilbert space in which von Neumann algebra is represented?